# How do I get predicted values with the glmnet (lasso)?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, anova, p-value

I was able to use glmnet to create a linear model using the Lasso method. Now I want to use that model to get predicted values.

```r
LASSO_BestK_LM <- cv.glmnet(
    x = X, 
    y = as.matrix(dataAll$LGsevenDayAnswerCnt), 
    family = "gaussian", 
    alpha = 1, # 0 for ridge regression, 1 for lasso 
    standardize = TRUE, 
    intercept = TRUE, 
    nfolds = 3
)

bestK <- LASSO_BestK_LM$lambda.min

plot(LASSO_BestK_LM)

cat("best k is ", bestK, "\n")

LASSO_MOD_LM <- glmnet(
    x = X, 
    y = as.matrix(dataAll$LGsevenDayAnswerCnt), 
    family = "gaussian", 
    alpha = 1, 
    lambda = bestK, 
    standardize = TRUE, 
    intercept = TRUE
)
```

Comment: With `predict`, e.g. `m <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(model.matrix(mpg ~ ., mtcars), mtcars[[1]], alpha = 1);
predict(m, model.matrix(mpg ~ ., mtcars), s = m$lambda.min)`

Comment: is that getting the predicted value of the mtcars data? what if i wanted to get predicted values for new data?

Comment: It works the same way; just pass a different matrix of x-values into `predict`.

Comment: See `?predict.glmnet`. There's a `newx` argument you can give new data to. Examples at the bottom of the help page.